# Secure api in api management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I published rest api from api management and now is there any way that I can secure the access to my api and that should show restriction error if someone want to consume my api

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for securing your API.
You have to choose the correct one based on your requirement.
And of, you can combine all of them.

You can do this with OAuth:
[Protect an API in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)

> In this article, you'll learn high level steps to configure your Azure API Management instance to protect an API, by using the OAuth 2.0 protocol with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

You can do this with Certificates:
[How to secure APIs using client certificate authentication in API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients)

> API Management provides the capability to secure access to APIs (i.e., client to API Management) using client certificates. You can validate certificates presented by the connecting client and check certificate properties against desired values using policy expressions.

And you can use SubscriptionKeys:
[Subscriptions in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions)

> In Azure API Management, subscriptions are the most common way for API consumers to access APIs published through an API Management instance. This article provides an overview of the concept.

> By publishing APIs through API Management, you can easily secure API access using subscription keys. Developers who need to consume the published APIs must include a valid subscription key in HTTP requests when calling those APIs. Without a valid subscription key, the calls are:
>
> - Rejected immediately by the API Management gateway.
> - Not forwarded to the back-end services.

If the Subscription-Key is invalid, the following error with status code 401 will be returned:

[image]

```json
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription."
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer will go through it also I want to know if someone uses my api after securing will they receive any error message

Comment: and all cases a 401 Unauthorized will be returned if key, certificate,... is invalid or missing